# How to rotate model in three.js in axis as it was created?

Tags: three.js, blender

I've stuck trying to find the way to determine axis of loaded object. For example, I have .stl created in Blender. Blender uses different directions of axis, so loaded object has wrong rotation.

Is there any way to correctly compare axis in threejs and axis which was used for object creation?

Comment: Maybe you should simply align/rotate the camera so your view corresponds to the blender system?

Comment: @Wilt Yes, I'm doing it this way right now(rotating model actually). But I would like to know is there more universal solution or not. Actually I dont know where model was created. If model was created via an app which uses three.js(for example) or smth else with the same direction of axis, then I shouldn't rotate camera/model.

Comment: If you don't have this information (the axes) somehow stored in the exported model file I would say it will be hard to determine the orientation. I would suggest going for the most commonly used configuration (so most likely z-axis is up).